# PS3 Ideal NAT Type

Tags: nat, ps3, playstation

On the "Internet Connection Test" on my PlayStation 3, it lists my "NAT Type" as "Type 2."

What is the ideal NAT Type and how does the NAT Type affect my games and streaming media?

Comment: Do you already know the difference between the difference types?

Comment: short answer, Type-2 is the best balance of functionality and security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The NAT type is defined by the way your internet router is set up.*

NAT type 1 exposes the PS3 to the internet proper, and any inbound traffic to your internet connection will hit the PS3, unless it is destined for a different device on your home network. This will likely allow any PS3 traffic to be negotiated quickly and unhindered, but opens you up to people exploiting security flaws which may be in the console.

NAT type 2 is what you will most likely be using already. Here your PS3 will not be directly exposed to the internet, any inbound connections will first have to be established by the PS3, then replied to by the other end. This is a far more secure setup, though you may have connection issues in some circumstances. However these issues will probably be edge cases, and this setup is very unlikely to cause performance issues.

To summarise, you have to set up your internet router correctly to change which NAT you are using, this cannot be done pureley on the PS3 end. NAT 1 is *less secure* but is less likely to cause you any type of connection issues, NAT 2 is the default for all home networking environments and should function perfectly.

If you have connection issues with a particular game or service then it may be worth looking into settting up NAT 1.

[Some more information...](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/11931)